# Шифрование WPF SQLSERVER Entity Framework

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

есть клиент серверное приложение на wpf c# с использованием Entity Framework и Sql Server, нужно зашифровать данные с помощью sql server ( да там есть выбор даже зашифровать столбец,это все хорошо) Не знаю, что нужно прописать в вижуал студио (( 
Нигде не могу найти ответ. Тем более половина нужного итак прописывается Entity Framework. Что нужно прописать в вижуал, чтоб корректно совершалась работа с данными после шифрования?

Comment: Опишите подробнее: EF6 или EF Core, какой версии SqlServer, нужно шифровать всю базу или отдельные колонки.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov EF6, точнее я добавила Entity Framework через nuget  в вижуал вот, отдельные столбцы, типа там паспортные данные ит п. SqlServer 2017